# Error: Cannot use vector unsigned long long[2] to initialize vector unsigned long long[2]

Tags: c++, swap, intrinsics, sunstudio

We are testing under Sun Studio 12.3. We are catching a compiler error that's not present under 12.4 and later. Its not present under 12.1 and earlier, but that's because the compiler [has trouble with AES instructions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/296221). Its also not present under other compilers, like Clang, GCC, ICPC and VC++. The error is:

```
/opt/solarisstudio12.3/bin/CC -DDEBUG -g3 -xO0 -D__SSE2__ -D__SSE3__ -D__SSSE3__ \
-D__SSE4_1__ -D__SSE4_2__ -D__AES__ -D__PCLMUL__ -D__RDRND__ -D__RDSEED__ -D__AVX__ \
-D__AVX2__ -D__BMI__ -D__BMI2__  -native -m64 -KPIC -template=no%extdef -c rijndael.cpp

"/opt/solarisstudio12.3/prod/include/CC/Cstd/algorithm", line 283: Error: Cannot use vector unsigned long long[2] to initialize vector unsigned long long[2].
"rijndael.cpp", line 277:     Where: While instantiating "std::swap<vector unsigned long long[2]>(unsigned long long(&)[2], unsigned long long(&)[2])".
"rijndael.cpp", line 277:     Where: Instantiated from non-template code.
1 Error(s) detected.
gmake: *** [rijndael.o] Error 2
gmake: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
ERROR: failed to make cryptest.exe
```

The code in question is:

```
std::swap(*(__m128i*)(rk), *(__m128i*)(rk+4*m_rounds));
```

I have a couple of questions:

- What is the compiler having trouble with?
- <strike>What is the best way to clear the error?</strike>

<strike>I have to ask the second question because I'm not sure of SunCC and the `__m128i` type given I could use raw `memcpy`, try to write my own swap, or even try an [`iter_swap`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6224830/608639) without the dereference.</strike>

Comment: Support for `std::swap` with C-arrays was added in C++11; have you enabled C++11/14 for your compiler?

Comment: @ildjarn - Ah, thank you very much. I believe Sun Studio 12.2 is C++03 only. In this case, how does one write a swap given `__m128i` is opaque? Should I simply `memcpy` it?

Comment: The general implementation of `swap` will typically create a temporary like `T temp( b );` where `b` is a formal argument of reference type. Prior to C++11 this would be invoked for raw arrays as actual arguments. And that doesn't compile (just like `int x[3]; int y[3]( x );` doesn't compile).

Comment: @ildjarn - you should probably provide an answer. You provided the critical piece of information by answering *"What is the compiler having trouble with?"*. I did not realize it was non-standard, and every other compiler accepts it (even Sun Studio 12.3, which is also C++03).

Comment: @jww : I'd rather not, given I don't have a good solution for you. But feel free to self-answer with whatever details you think are pertinent. :-]

Comment: Now related: [How to swap two __m128i variables in C++03 given its an opaque type and an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38417413)